# how to set x axis scroll bar to a handsontable

Tags: javascript, html, css, handsontable

I am using JarvisWidget library to create widgets, in which i create a table using handsontable library. but the table exceeds the widhth of the widget. I want to put a scrollbar. I tried in css wdith:100%; and then overflow-x:scroll. but it didn't working.[image]

That how its coming. But i want to put a scrollbar and and show the whole table inside the widget

here is my table code:

```
 <section class="col-md-12">
     <div id="table_example" class="handsontable"></div>
 </section>
 var container = document.getElementById('table_example');

 var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
        data: handsOnData,
        renderAllRows: true,
        fixedRowsTop: 0,
        colHeaders: true,
        rowHeaders: true,
        formulas: true,
        comments: true,
        manualRowResize: true,
        manualColumnResize: true
    });
```

Comment: I also give a width to the table params, but that is not working also

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it..

```
  windowWidth = ($("#wid-id-1").width())-100; //retrieve specific div width
  windowHeight = $(window).height(); //retrieve current window height
  $("#table_example").css('width',windowWidth);
  $("#table_example").css('height',windowHeight);
```

wid-id-1is the id under which the section is written. or the we can say the parent div of the table. And add style="overflow:hidden" to the table